# Code injection - possible ways of attack

Tags: javascript, html, security

a friend of mine became a victim of code injection to his website. In some pages, there was a iframe inserted (if you're interested in the exact code, I can post it).

Now I'm thinking of how this could have happened - unfortunately, I'm not an expert in web programming (I usually code in C/C++), therefore I need your help. What suprises me is the following: The website is a static website, only HTML + CSS (not even HTML5, no PHP, no databases and other stuff like that). The only little script that is not HTML, but JavaScript is this little thing:

```
<script language="jscript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
function navigation(id, link) {
    window.document.images[id].src = link;
}

function archiv (id)
{
 if (document.getElementById("link_" + id).style.display == 'none') {
  document.getElementById("link_" + id).style.display = "";
  }
 else   {
  document.getElementById("link_" + id).style.display = "none";
  }
 }
-->
</script>
```

in order to create a dropdown effect in the menu.

Now my question is: Since there are no ways of injecting code through some dynamic scripts on the page: Can this little script be attacked? And if not: Are there any other ways - apart from password attack at the FTP server - which could have caused the damage?

Comment: As you know, Javascript (in this context) is a client-side thing.  It tells us nothing about the security (or lack thereof) on the server involved ;)

Comment: What if, I don't know, someone were to type something like `javascript:archiv('codeInjection')` in their browser's URL bar?

Comment: So, yes, my guess would be that someone "directly" hacked the server.

Comment: This might be more appropriate for security.stackexchange.com, because there are a lot of ways to attack a webserver and change content.

Comment: Didn't know about security.se.com - this place is growing kinda fast ;)

Comment: @ManofSnow Depending on what you do in there, it might indeed break something for the person who executed it; but nothing that will harm other users or even the server. Fixing is as simple as pressing F5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very unlikely that this snippet of javascript is a security vulnerability. Javascript is executed on the client, not on the server. The only way for Javascript to cause any damage on the server would be when it would in some way communicate back to the server (like with xmlHttpRequest) and attack a vulnerable script there. But in that case the vulnerability would be the script on the server. When there is a vulnerability in javascript, it's usually harmful for the user, not the server (like an XSS attack which steals their cookie and allows others to log into their account)

When there is really no active content on the server like you say, the attack likely happened over an entirely different vector.

And are you sure that there is really no active content on the webserver? When it's a shared hosting, there might be some preinstalled management tools which might be vulnerable.

Maybe the admin used a weak FTP password? Or used the same password for some untrustworthy service where he registered with an email address like admin@domain.com?

Comment: Thx for the answer - The website is hosted using a very basic package at a regular hosting provider, so not on an own server. I would assume that the provider uses virtual servers, but I don't know. As it's a very basic package, we don't even have root access or anything like that, only FTP access in order to upload files

Comment: @Chris When you can be 100% sure that your password didn't get compromised, you should inform the hoster about the incident and unless they immediately take care of the problem, identify it and fix it (unlikely considering that you seem to have picked the cheapest offer you can find), you should move somewhere else.